# React Native WebView does not scroll horizontally on android

Tags: react-native

Here is my code:

```
<View style={{ height: this.state.height, ...props.style }}>
    <WebView
                ref="child"
                {...this.props}
                scalesPageToFit={false}
                scrollEnabled={true}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
            domStorageEnabled={true}
            startInLoadingState={true}
                onMessage={ this.handleMessage.bind(this) }
                source={{ html }}
    />
  </View>
```

This works fine on iOS build (Scrolls horizontally) but does not work on Android.

Answer (score 0):

react native WebView has been deprecated you should now use 
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview

Comment: I am using https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview

Answer (score 0):

First answer is right, you should use react-native-webview now.
And, your problem may be related with your View wrapper I think.

Comment: I am using react-native-webview. And the wrapper is to get dynamic height of the webview based on its content. Its working fine on iOS.

Comment: You could be right but iOS and Android can behave differently sometimes in react-native